# Can I deploy both python 2 and 3 django app with apache using mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I am running on ubuntu 14.04. And I am wondering can I deploy my django apps coded with python 2 and 3 together with apache and mod_wsgi? and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot. The mod_wsgi module for Apache is compiled for one Python version only. You cannot load more than one instance of mod_wsgi into Apache at the same time.

What you may be better off doing is using mod_wsgi-express, which allows running of Apache with mod_wsgi in a more easy way where mod_wsgi is a part of your Python installation or virtual environment. You could then have any front end web server proxy to different mod_wsgi-express instances where each is using different Python versions.

See:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Also go back and read through past mod_wsgi articles where I have talked about mod_wsgi-express and proxying on my blog site:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au