# How can I deploy multiple Python 2 and 3 Django projects on one Apache server?

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

**Problem:** There is a similar question on Stack Overflow: ["Can I deploy both Python 2 and 3 Django app with Apache using mod_wsgi?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075340/can-i-deploy-both-python-2-and-3-django-app-with-apache-using-mod-wsgi) From the answer there I know that it is possible two have multiple Django projects (written in Python 2 and 3) on one Apache server. However, I can't manage to make this work.

**What I have so far**:

1. I'm using Linux (Debian/Ubuntu).
2. Three Django projects are stored in three separate Python Virtual Environments (i.e. py3venv1, py3venv2, py2venv1):

   ```
   /var/www/

   .........py3venv1/                             <-- Python 3 venv
   ..................bin/
   ..................include/
   ..................lib/
   ..................project1/                    <-- Python 3 Django Project
   ........................../manage.py
   ........................../project1/wsgi.py
   ........................../myapp

   .........py3venv2/                             <-- Python 3 venv
   ..................bin/
   ..................include/
   ..................lib/
   ..................project2/                    <-- Python 3 Django Project
   ........................../manage.py
   ........................../project2/wsgi.py
   ........................../myapp

   .........py2venv1/                             <-- Python 2 venv
   ..................bin/
   ..................include/
   ..................lib/
   ..................project3/                    <-- Python 2 Django Project
   ........................../manage.py
   ........................../project3/wsgi.py
   ........................../myapp
   ```
3. I installed mod_wsgi for Python3 (`pip3 install mod_wsgi`)
4. Apache configuration: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` for Projects 1 and 2 (Python3 only), Project 3 (Python 2) is not configured:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       # Project 1 (Python3)
       WSGIScriptAlias /project1 /var/www/py3venv1/project1/project1/wsgi.py process-group=group1
       WSGIDaemonProcess group1 python-home=/var/www/py3venv1/lib/python3.5 python-path=/var/www/py3venv1/project1
       WSGIProcessGroup group1
       Alias /project1/static /var/www/py3env1/project1/assets
       <Directory /var/www/py3venv1/project1/project1>
           <Files wsgi.py>
               Require all granted
           </Files>
       </Directory>

       # Project 2 (Python3)
       WSGIScriptAlias /project2 /var/www/py3venv2/project2/project2/wsgi.py process-group=group2
       WSGIDaemonProcess group2 python-home=/var/www/py3venv2/lib/python3.5 python-path=/var/www/py3venv2/project2
       WSGIProcessGroup group2
       Alias /project2/static /var/www/py3env2/project2/assets
       <Directory /var/www/py3venv2/project2/project2>
           <Files wsgi.py>
               Require all granted
           </Files>
       </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

**Outcome:** Both Python 3 projects work fine. Python 2 project does not work.

**Question:** How can I make all three Django projects work on Apache?

Answer (score 1):

The other question you link clearly says you can't have both Python 2 and 3 applications in the same Apache server instance. How do you read it as saying you can?

If you want different Python versions, you need to use mod_wsgi-express mentioned in that other post and run it as separate instance and have front end Apache proxy requests for specific site through to the other instance.

Have you looked at mod-wsgi-express at all and tried to get it installed and running?